# How do they call this security device mostly used in trains?

Tags: vocabulary

Some locomotives have a special sensor that the train operator must rub periodically to let the monitoring system know they did not fall asleep. How do they call this sensor?

*A simple search reveals a lot of anecdotes or news featuring aslept train operators, but I could not find any reference to that kind of sensor. I believe that it is called “main morte” in French but I could not confirm this and this expression also refers to some law from the middle-age, which makes validation or translation difficult.*

Comment: It sounds like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_man%27s_switch to me.

Comment: In the UK it's called a dead man's handle. http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dead-man's-handle

Comment: @Michael In English, we ask ***What** do they/you/I call this something?*

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia describes this as a *[dead man's vigilance device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead-man%27s_vigilance_device)*. As the comments suggested, *dead man's switch* or *dead man's handle* are alternative names. A more general term for this type of device is *[kill switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill_switch)* or *emergency stop*.

Wikipedia also lists several other alternative names:

> Replacement of "switch" with "control" or name denoting a specific type of switch, e.g., "button", "trigger", "throttle", "pedal", "handle", or "brake"
>
> Replacement of "dead man's" or "dead-man" with "enabling" or "live-man" (commonly used in the robotics industry)
>
> "Driver's Safety Device" ("DSD") (the official term in the UK for switches of this type as used on railway trains)
>
> "Operator Presence Control" ("OPC")
>
> "Vigilance control"
>
> "Alerter system" (in higher-order systems in which the switch activates to sound an alarm rather than deactivates to disable the higher-order system)
>
> "Kill cord" on a boat.

Comment: I think a "kill switch" and a "dead man's switch" work differently. We use (press, touch, etc.) the former to halt the machine (or the operation). We use the latter to keep it going.

Comment: @DamkerngT. "kill switch" is just more general. It can refer to anything that, when tripped for any reason, stops the mechanism or process. It can be manual or automatic.

Comment: That's right, but we would have to keep touching (or holding, pressing, etc.) the "dead man's switch" if we want a machine to keep running, if I understand these two kinds of switches correctly.

Comment: To my mind a kill switch is something which must be activated to cease operation (i.e. a big red button on machinery/workshop tools), while a dead man switch is released to cease operation (i.e. a lever/spring release switch is activated to continue operation and ceases when released). A subtle but important distinction.